# Can't using Deno-Db to connect to PostgressSql - Module not found 'events.ts'

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, deno, denodb

I'm trying to connect to Postgres sql using Deno-db, I've grabbed this code below from [official documentation](https://deno.land/manual@v1.35.3/basics/connecting_to_databases#denodb) and edit it to connect to my local server.

```js
import {
    Database,
    PostgresConnector,
} from "https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.4.0/mod.ts";

// SQLite3Connector, MySQLConnector, PostgresConnector...
const connector = new PostgresConnector({
    uri: "localhost",
    port: 5433,
    password: "",
    database: "mora",
    host: "localhost",
    username: "postgres",
});

// const db = new Database(connector);

// If you need debug logs, set `debug` to `true`
const db = new Database({ connector, debug: true });
```

#### The Error:

`error: Module not found "https://deno.land/std/node/events.ts". at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Zhomart/dex/930253915093e1e08d48ec0409b4aee800d8bd0c/lib-dyn/deps.ts:7:24`

I've tried to change the import version from latest to the redirected version (@1.4.0)

```
import {
    Database,
    PostgresConnector,
} from "https://deno.land/x/denodb@v1.4.0/mod.ts";
```

Still facing the same issue.

> My Deno version:
> deno 1.35.3 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
> v8 11.6.189.12
> typescript 5.1.6
> Node Version: v12 to v19.

> I also tried changing my IP Address using VPN.

#### Another question:

Is Deno-Db designed to connect to multiple Databases? Am I missing something?